# How to create a table with array in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new in programming world. I am trying to create an application with laravel5.1 . I have bunch of data as multidimensional array. Now I want to create a table with these data. Return data as like below:

```
              [
                [
                    { "id":581,"user_id":101,"amount":"500.00","charge":"10.00", "rcvd_account":"01916811723","account_type":"personal","acc_carrier":"bKash","req_date":"2016-04-26 12:46:43","response_date":"2016-05-24 15:41:40","remark":"","tnx_id":"bkp_71535117","status":1,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":712,"user_id":429,"amount":"200.00","charge":"10.00","rcvd_account":"01723214356","account_type":"personal","acc_carrier":"bKash","req_date":"2016-05-01 23:05:00","response_date":"2016-05-24 15:40:53","remark":"Mon chaise tai","tnx_id":"bkp_30513790","status":2,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":995,"user_id":17,"amount":"2000.00","charge":"100.00","rcvd_account":"01819529861","account_type":"agent","acc_carrier":"dbblm","req_date":"2016-05-24 17:30:25","response_date":"2016-05-24 17:30:51","remark":"","tnx_id":"dbma_18209839","status":1,"processed_by":"824"}
                ],

                [
                    {"id":1004,"user_id":560,"amount":"1200.00","charge":"24.00","rcvd_account":"0191125478","account_type":"personal","acc_carrier":"dbblm","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:30:54","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:35","remark":"Account balance and transaction amount mismatch. Account balance is BDT 9000 grater than transaction amount.","tnx_id":"dbmp_98010253","status":2,"processed_by":"824"}
                ],
                [
                    {"id":1005,"user_id":598,"amount":"5000.00","charge":"250.00","rcvd_account":"01819529861","account_type":"agent","acc_carrier":"bKash","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:32:40","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:37","remark":"","tnx_id":"bka_89541626","status":1,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":1006,"user_id":598,"amount":"1980.00","charge":"10.00","rcvd_account":"01911205478","account_type":"personal","acc_carrier":"bKash","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:33:24","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:51","remark":"","tnx_id":"bkp_64898681","status":1,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":1007,"user_id":598,"amount":"5000.00","charge":"250.00","rcvd_account":"0185421365","account_type":"agent","acc_carrier":"dbblm","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:33:44","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:53","remark":"","tnx_id":"dbma_8505249","status":1,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":1008,"user_id":598,"amount":"2000.00","charge":"100.00","rcvd_account":"0214214521","account_type":"agent","acc_carrier":"dbblm","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:34:02","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:49","remark":"Account balance and transaction amount mismatch. Account balance is BDT 15240 grater than transaction amount.","tnx_id":"dbma_97558593","status":2,"processed_by":"824"},

                    {"id":1009,"user_id":598,"amount":"200.00","charge":"4.00","rcvd_account":"018954213652","account_type":"personal","acc_carrier":"dbblm","req_date":"2016-05-24 19:34:41","response_date":"2016-05-24 19:36:54","remark":"","tnx_id":"dbmp_21560669","status":1,"processed_by":"824"}
                ]
              ]
```

And I want to create a table As Like below:

```
<table class="table m-t-40">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Purpose</th>
                    <th>DC</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>satataunit</td>
                        <td>bKash</td>
                        <td>500.00</td>
                        <td rowspan="3">2700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>satataunit</td>
                        <td>bKash</td>
                        <td>200.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>satataunit</td>
                        <td>dbblm</td>
                        <td>2000.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mahienterprise</td>
                        <td>dbblm</td>
                        <td>1200.00</td>
                        <td rowspan="1">1200</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mizanur</td>
                        <td>bKash</td>
                        <td>5000.00</td>
                        <td rowspan="5">14180</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mizanur</td>
                        <td>bKash</td>
                        <td>1980.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mizanur</td>
                        <td>dbblm</td>
                        <td>5000.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mizanur</td>
                        <td>dbblm</td>
                        <td>2000.00</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
                        <td>mizanur</td>
                        <td>dbblm</td>
                        <td>200.00</td>
                    </tr>


            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Total</th>
                <th >18080</th>
             </tr>
            </tfoot>
    </table>
```

I am trying with below code:

```
    $total = 0;
        $sn = 0;

        foreach($results as $key => $element) {


            $sn++;

            for($i=0; $i<count($element); $i++){

               $total += $element[$i]->amount;

               $table .= "<tr><td>".$sn."</td><td>Withdrawl Balance</td><td>". AppHelper::getDc($element[$i]->user_id) ."</td><td>". $element[$i]->acc_carrier ."</td><td>". $element[$i]->amount. (end($element) ? '</td><td rowspan="'.count($element).'">'.$total.'</td>': '')."</tr>";

            }
$table .= "</tbody></table>";
```

And My Output data as like below:

```
<table class='table m-t-30'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
            <th>DC</th>
            <th>Acc. Carrier</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>arifdc</td>
        <td>dbblm</td>
        <td>560.00</td>
        <td rowspan="2">560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>arifdc</td>
        <td>bKash</td>
        <td>350.00</td>
        <td rowspan="2">910</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>bKash</td>
        <td>1200.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">2110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>dbblm</td>
        <td>2000.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">4110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>dbblm</td>
        <td>1000.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">5110</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>bKash</td>
        <td>1520.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">6630</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>bKash</td>
        <td>1980.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">8610</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Withdrawl Balance</td>
        <td>mahienterprise</td>
        <td>dbblm</td>
        <td>3500.00</td>
        <td rowspan="6">12110</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is problem with "rowspan" its not set as expected. Please experts help me to find out where is the problem is? And please advise me how can I reach as my expected goal? Thanks in advance dears

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is not clear to me. You can try the following way:

```
$table .= "<tbody>";

for($i=0; $i<count($element); $i++){

   $table .= "<tr><td>".$sn."</td><td>Withdrawl Balance</td><td>". AppHelper::getDc($element[$i]->user_id) ."</td><td>". $element[$i]->acc_carrier ."</td><td>". $element[$i]->amount."</td>";

   // If table has the extra column for rowspan then $extraRow has value otherwise it will be empty

   $extraRow = '';
   $total    = 0.0;

   if ($i == 0) {
       for($i = 0; $i<=2; ++$i) {
           // SUM of first three rows
           $total += $element[i]->amount;
       }
       $extraRow .= "<td rowspan='3'>$total</td>";
   } elseif ($i == 3) {
       // SUM of forth row
       $total = $element[3]->amount;
       $extraRow .= "<td rowspan='1'>$total</td>";
   } elseif ($i == 4) {
       for ($i = 4; $i<=8; ++$i) {
           // Sum of fifth to ninth rows
           $total += $element[i]->amount;
       }
       $extraRow .= "<td rowspan='5'>$total</td>";
   }

   // Adding $extraRow
   $table .= $extraRow.'</tr>';
}
$table .= "</tbody>";
```

Try to use Laravel Blade Template.
[Laravel Blade Template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

And also try to retrieve datas from database using Eloquent ORM.
[Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a db and tables already created,

I would suggest you use laravel's seeds to populate your db:

Then query these results using laravel's eloquent/model functions

pass them to your view and use blade to generate your table

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Purpose</th>
       <th>DC</th>
       <th>Acc. Carrier</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach ($results as $result)
      <tr>
         <td>{{$result->id}}</td>
         <td>{{$result->purpose}}</td>
         <td>{{$result->dc}}</td>
         <td>{{$result->carrier}}</td>
         <td>{{$result->amount}}</td>
         <td rowspan="6">{{$result->total}}</td>
         </tr>
   @endforeach

</table>
```